# Error with rendering rendering quadratic function in tikZ, using pgfplots package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot this function in TikZ using the pgfplots package: [image]

I am currently running into the problem where the function is rendering as a straight line on the X-axis. I am new to tikZ, and am not sure where the error in my code is with regards to entering this function. My code is as follows,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3,xmax=3,
    ymin=-2,ymax=2,
    grid=both,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    axis lines=middle,
    minor tick num=5,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
 ]
 \addplot[blue, smooth] (x,{(-x^4+x^3+1.9x^2+0.1x+0.2)/3.6});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: It is `\addplot[blue, smooth] {(-x^4+x^3+1.9*x^2+0.1*x+0.2)/3.6};`. That is, you need to remove `(x,` in the beginning, `)` in the end and add `*` whenever you multiply two expressions.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you, the issue was that I was missing * in between factors inside of the function. Curiously, I was able to achieve the desired result simply by only changing that. I.e, the code 
```\addplot[blue, smooth] (x,{(-x^4+x^3+1.9*(x^2)+0.1*(x)+0.2)/3.6});
```
achieves the desired result. Could you please explain the purpose of removing the ```(x,``` ```)```?

Comment: @MarkBalboni Yes, but the suggested syntax is what the manual recommends, and is shorter. It is true, though, that the real issue is the missing multiplication signs.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you for the help. I will have to consult the manual further.

Comment: As any applied mathematician can tell you , the correct form is `((((-x+1)*x+1.9)*x+0.1)*x+0.2)/3.6`;